# SQLCipher and Fabric/Crashlytics issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, crashlytics, sqlcipher, crashlytics-android

I have an android studio project using SQLCipher, no issues, but when I integrated the Fabric SDK and Crashlytic it is now crashing on Run with an Unsatisfied linker error when I load the libs for SQLCipher because it can't find the libstlport_shared.so

Any one else running this issue? I have no idea where to begin to troubleshoot this. Here is the error.

```
10-27 11:12:27.869: E/AndroidRuntime(4189): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapp.myapp-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libstlport_shared.so"
```

Comment: Are you running Android M?

Comment: No I am not. 5.1.1 on a Nexus 9

Answer (score 0):

SQLCipher for Android only includes `armeabi`, `armeabi-v7a`, and `x86` native libraries.  You might try removing the `arm64` versions of your other libraries (i.e., Fabric and Crashlytic) if possible to see if Android attempts to load just the `armeabi` version of all libraries.

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics and Fabric here. 

Following up on Nick's answer, if you need steps to remove the libraries, check out how to do that here: https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/ndk.html#universal-aar